# Prevent Expandable Ads as a Publisher

Tags: ads, google-ad-manager

I would like to understand how to prevent non-standard ad units from expanding on our site. Does this happen due to the iframe we have setup? Why does setting up size not suffice?

Defining ad size through SSP partner, through GAM and through our own config.